# Google maps javascript geolocation api isnt working on mobile devices

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, ionic-framework

I am building a hybrid mobile app using the ionic framework utilizing the google maps javascript api with geolocation. I followed the sample code from their site and the app runs fine when i run on the browser but  when i test on my android device, the map loads perfectly but the geolocation does not work at all. Any help/tips?

Comment: Add your code to your question please

Answer (score 0):

i things you used [ngCordova Plugins](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/)
its plugins used for getting current location of device [lat,lng] and its latlng to display in your map.

thanks and good luck.